# Issues getting json from webserver in iOS5

Tags: ios, json, ios5, nsdictionary, nsjsonserialization

I have a app that receive a feed from a server through json.

I have been building it for iOS5, but in the last weeks testing with iOS6. I tested today with a iOS5 device, and everything crashed.

The code looks like this:

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.myserver.com/news.json"]];
NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
```

It worked without problems, but now it returns a null. The data is not null.

Comment: Does the URL open in the browser?

Comment: Try using a simple NSURLConnection and log errors [if any]

Comment: The URL open, and is not empty. iOS6 devices receive without problems the feed.

Comment: Do you get any errors? Have you logged the error object?

Comment: Its looks like the problem reside in the conversion of `NSData` to `NSDictionary`with `NSJSONSerialization`. If I convert the `NSData` to `NSString` I got the JSON.

Comment: The error I getting from NSJSONSerialization is `Cocoa error 3840`

Comment: To print the error: NSError *error = nil;
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url options:kNilOptions error:&error];
    NSLog(@"%@",[error localizedDescription]);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was a duplicated key from the webserver. Now it works.

But it strange that the error is trigged in iOS5 and not in iOS6.

Answer (score 1):

Cocoa error 3840 means

> The data couldn’t be read because it has been corrupted. (No string
>   key for value in object around character 2.)

You should check your json with a validator like http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/ or  http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Comment: I checked it, and is valid. But look at my own answer above.